# Can I have a Wordpress site with a CakePHP subsite?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I'm hoping to build a website which needs to be done quickly.  The website itself should be fairly basic, so I was going to just do that in Wordpress.  However, it also needs functionality to allow people to register and then interact (none of this appears on the website, just a link to the user login bit). I think it's going to be easier to build that bit in CakePHP as it has some very specific functionality that I don't think I'd find a WP plugin for.

Is there a way that I can build my website.com in Wordpress and then have something like my website.com/userarea where user area is built in CakePHP?

Comment: I know it sounds condescending, but how about just trying it? Simply put your CakePHP app in a subdirectory of your WordPress installation and see what happens. Personally I'd simply put the CakePHP app on a subdomain.

Comment: Good thinking! Might just do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but requires a rather esoteric configuration of your webserver, and that's assuming you are proposing to implement the cakephp part with a front controller architecture. Even if you are a nginx/apache guru I'd recommend running the two components under different vhosts.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's helpful.  Anyone know whether there's an easier way to do something similar?  Basically what I want is a straightforward website and then a more complicated user area.